# Data stored in local storage are swapping with other parameters after several hours

Tags: html, angularjs, local-storage, blob

In my project,I'm using local storage to save some parameters and binding those parameters in HTML,The project is based on location Id,each location ID contains different data,when we run with different location id's all those respective details will save in the local storage on based on the location id,after several hours the values of several parameters are swapping.

can anyone suggest what might be the issue and the solution,I'll attach the snap of the local storage

Thanks in advance

[local storage detailed image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mgMI8.png)

Comment: make sure  there location id is unique right?

Comment: Location id will vary.From the image you can see the parameter s"templateLogo 1076.1010,templateLogo1270.0101,templateLogo2290.0202" where "1076.1010/1270.0101/2290.0202" are the location id's